# slurm --array two variables

Tags: bash, slurm, hpc

I have the following bash script that runs on a HPC using `slurm`:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name test
#SBATCH --ntasks 10
#SBATCH --time 00-01:00
#SBATCH --output out
#SBATCH --error err
#SBATCH --array=0-9

readarray -t VARS < list_VAR.txt
VAR=${VARS[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}
export VAR

bash data_0_"$VAR".sh
```

The above bash script sends 10 jobs (`#SBATCH --array=0-9`) to the HPC to run the `data_0_"$VAR".sh` script, where `"$VAR"` is a given string contained within the `list_VAR.txt` file.

Let's suppose now I have a second `list_VAR_2.txt` file that contains a list of numbers from 0 to 3 and I want to apply it to the `job-array` above, along with `list_VAR.txt`. The `data_0_"$VAR".sh` script to be ran will then convert to `data_"$VAR_2"_"$VAR".sh`.

Is there a way to add this further list of variables `list_VAR_2.txt` to the bash script?

Thanks

#####################

Update, list_VAR.txt

```
aa
bh
wwe
ftq
juu
d
8i
yz5
qq1p
m75
```

list_VAR_2.txt

```
0
1
2
3
```

Comment: Could you post a sample `list_VAR.txt` and `list_VAR_2.txt` please?

Answer (score 2):

You could load your `list_VAR_2.txt` content into an array like you did for the first file.  Then loop on the arrays to build your bash commands.

Ex:

```
#!/bin/bash

readarray -t VARS < list_VAR.txt
readarray -t VARS_2 < list_VAR_2.txt

for VAR in "${VARS[@]}"
do
    for VAR_2 in "${VARS_2[@]}"
    do
        bash data_"$VAR_2"_"$VAR".sh
    done
done
```

Or build the bash commands by specifying the indexes of the array elements you want.

Ex.

```
bash data_"${VARS[INDEX1]}"_"${VARS_2[INDEX2]}".sh
```

Comment: thanks but this doesn’t fit within the slurm bash script

Comment: ?? what does that mean, does not fit?

Comment: does not work..